# Jest Test of Material-UI Component to Simulate Button click event to fire a Redux Action function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

Not able to test `button.simulate("click")` on a Material-UI based Component having Button which fires 'loadAllData()' function on its onClick prop.

The below is my hooks based component

The full code for this component is [**here**](https://github.com/rohan-paul/find-most-popular-github-user-in-your-city/blob/master/src/containers/GithubMostPopularList/GithubMostPopularList.js)

```
const GithubMostPopularList = () => {
  const globalStore = useSelector(state => state.globalStore)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const loadAllData = () => {
    const city = globalStore.city_to_search
    setcurrentCityShown(city)
    dispatch(loadMostPopularUsers(city, page, rowsPerPage))
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.tableAndFabContainer}>
        {globalStore.loading ? (
          <div className={classes.spinner}>
            <LoadingSpinner />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className={classes.table}>            
            <div className={classes.inputandButtonContainer}>
              <Button
                onClick={loadAllData}
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                color="primary"
                disabled={globalStore.city_to_search === ""}
              >
                <Typography
                  variant="h3"
                  className={classes.modalButtonLabelEnabled}
                >
                  Load City Data
                </Typography>
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
              <EachUserListItem
                currentCityShown={currentCityShown}
              ></EachUserListItem>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default GithubMostPopularList
```

And below is my test, which fails giving me **`TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadAllData' of null'**

```
  it("should trigger onClick on on Button press", () => {
    const wrapperComp = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={globalTheme}>
          <GithubMostPopularList />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>,
    )

    const spy1 = jest.spyOn(wrapperComp.instance(), "loadAllData")
    const button = wrapperComp.find(Button).last()
    button.simulate("click")
    wrapperComp.update()   

    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

Will highly appreciate any guidance or help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you had to use mount to avoid the error of shallowing a material component without a provider.

but here is what I usually do. I unwrap the component then it is ok to shallow it.

```
import unwrap from '@material-ui/core/test-utils/unwrap';

const UnwrappedComponent: any = unwrap((GithubMostPopularList as unknown as React.ReactElement<any>));

it('should trigger onClick on on Button press', () => {
    const wrapperComp = shallow(<UnwrappedComponent />);
    jest.spyOn(wrapperComp.instance(), 'loadAllData');
    const button = wrapperComp.find(Button);
    button.simulate('click');
    wrapperComp.update();
    expect(wrapperComp.instance().loadAllData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Tried that, did not help, with UnwrappedComponent and shallow rendering also gettting the same error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadAllData' of null"